# What is the alternative of jsplumb while using Vue js?

Tags: vuejs2, quasar

I'm developing an app using quasar framework and Vue js. Initially, I used Drag and drop functionality and linking them with connectors in my web app using **jquery UI** and **jsplumb**.

Basically, the jsplumb library is a plugin for jquery and jquery occupies more memory space comparing to Vue js.

So, I thought of using pure **Vue js** functionalities for my requirement. So is there any Vue js plugins which does following tasks?

1) Able to drag blocks from one container and drop it to the specific location in another container.

2) Able to add endpoints(as provided in jsplumb) to the dropped blocks

3) And able to draw a connecting link between any blocks in the container.

So is there any way of replacing **jquery** and **jsplumb** with only pure **Vue js and Quasar**?

Answer (score 1):

as per documentation: [JSPlumb features](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/features) there's a vue version, but it looks like it's paid.

Also in other part it says "Although jsPlumb has no dependency on jQuery, it also supports jQuery selectors as arguments for elements (vanilla jsPlumb because jQuery's selector object is list-like, ie. it has a length property and indexed accessors)." So you don't need jQuery to use JsPlumb. We got that cover.

Then you can use [Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) which uses vue.sortable as well, for the drag and drop part.

So, what if you already have a bunch of selectors with jsplumb in Jquery? you could replace jquery with this selector method:

```
window.$ = function(selector) {
    var selectorType = 'querySelectorAll';

    if (selector.indexOf('#') === 0) {
        selectorType = 'getElementById';
        selector = selector.substr(1, selector.length);
    }

    return document[selectorType](selector);
};
```

Snippet from here: https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/selectors/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But Draggable uses vue.sortable, which can be dropped in list manner. But is there anything which drops the blocks to the specific location in a div/container?

Comment: @Darshantheerth There's a vue-dragula (a vue implementation of dragula), but i never used so not sure if it will help.